# How to switch between different characters in the same scene?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

Anybody know how to make it? I want to switch between two characters in the same scene. For example, in the video, 5:16, the moon animatronic switches into the sun animatronic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKEff29bHFc&t=68s

[image]

[image]

Comment: since (maybe my eyes are too old) i don't see any animation there (except some shaking)...so just hide the one character and make the other one visible?

Comment: or even give the same animation to both the 2 characters and make one invisible and the other one visible at the frame you want